# set swf scalemode to showall using swf library or php

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I have a lot of swf files that have the Stage.scaleMode property set to noscale.  When embedding the videos they do not scale at all (which would be expected).

I am looking for a way to programmatically change the scaleMode to showAll in my swf files.  Ideally I would like to process a swf file using PHP and alter the file.  Otherwise some kind of swf library would be nice.

So my question would be is there an easy way to open a swf file in binary mode, jump to the part of the swf file where it stores the scaleMode and alter the file using PHP?  Or, is there a swf library that can do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

All swf files are scalable.. its the configuration you put it on the page with which decides its scale mode. but you can easily override it by changing the scale property, in the html you use to include it with. Atleast. since you want to use php to get the job done, i tought you are making a website:

you can set an property [scale](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html). Which has 4 diffirent modes :  default, exactfit, noborder and noscale

If this is for some reason not possible, you could concider using the [ming](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php) library in php. But the scale property in html should always be prefered over altering the swf file

Comment: the swf files are not ones I created in flash, but screencast recordings.  thus I have no way to modify the original.  they definitely do not scale as I have done extensive testing.

I looked over ming and it seems to be for creating swf movies, not for modifying ones already created.  I will take a closer look

Comment: You can always concider reading the swf specifications ( found on the adobe site) and make something yourself.  Or open the swf inside another swf file and control that one. But if you dont ahve the flash files. you will always need hacky solutions i think.